# I need to sum all the values in a column across multiple files

Tags: awk

I have a directory with multiple csv text files, each with a single line in the format:

`field1,field2,field3,560`

I need to output the sum of the fourth field across all files in a directory (can be hundreds or thousands of files). So for an example of:

```
file1.txt
field1,field2,field3,560

file2.txt
field1,field2,field3,415

file3.txt
field1,field2,field3,672
```

The output would simply be:
`1647`

I've been trying a few different things, with the most promising being an `awk` command that I found here in response to another user's question.  It doesn't quite do what I need it to do, and I am an awk newb so I'm unsure how to modify it to work for my purpose:

`awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$4;next}{print $4+a[FNR]:' file1.txt file2.txt`

This correctly outputs `975`.

However if I try pass it a 3rd file, rather than add field 4 from all 3 files, it adds file1 to file2, then file1 to file3:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$4;next}{print $4+a[FNR]:' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
975
1232
```

Can anyone show me how I can modify this awk statement to accept more than two files or, ideally because there are thousands of files to sum up, an * to output the sum of the fourth field of all files in the directory?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: If its always $4 and no commas within fields: `awk -F ',' '{sum+=$4} END{print sum}' file1 file1 file1 file1` = 2240

Comment: for 4 files simply do `awk -F ',' '{sum+=$4} END{print sum}' file[1-4]`

Comment: @AndreWildberg This works perfectly!  Allows me to pass * instead of filenames to get every file in a dir.  Excellent, thank you so much. :) Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can choose from one of the fine answers below! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple issues with the current code:

- `NR==FNR` is used to indicate special processing for the 1st file; in this case there is no processing that is 'special' for just the 1st file (ie, all files are to be processed the same)
- an array (eg, `a[NR]`) is used to maintain a set of values; in this case you only have one global value to maintain so there is no need for an array

Since you're only looking for one global sum, a bit more simpler code should suffice:

```
$ awk -F',' '{sum+=$4} END {print sum+0}' file{1..3}.txt
1647
```

**NOTES:**

- in the (unlikely?) case all files are empty, `sum` will be undefined so `print sum` will display a blank link; `sum+0` insures we print `0` if `sum` remains undefined (ie, all files are empty)
- for a variable number of files `file{1..3}.txt` can be replaced with whatever pattern will match on the desired set of files, eg, `file*.txt`, `*.txt`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Here we go (no need to test `NR==FNR` in a concatenation):

```
$ cat file{1,2,3}.txt | awk -F, '{count+=$4}END{print count}' 
1647
```

Or *same-same*  (without wasting some pipe(s)):

```
$ awk -F, '{count+=$4}END{print count}' file{1,2,3}.txt
1647
```

Comment: thai pride week ? or it's for that dead soccer kid ?

Comment: It's just the local expression to say it. I just though it's funny. I don't care about news

Comment: yeah unfortunately i'm not british or irish so i guess i missed the humor part. sorrie

Comment: actually … need to type that properly - "humour"

Comment: I'm not in Fr but in Th ;)

Comment: like where? Sukhumvit ?

Comment: North Thai, why? You know the place? BKK is too hot

Comment: i don't know it well, but yes `BKK` is waaaay too hot, both the city and inside the airport terminal. Now pile on global warming then it becomes real fun

Comment: Maybe Laos will be a better place in some weeks

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -MList::Util=sum0 -F, -lane'push @a,$F[3];END{print sum0 @a}' file{1..3}.txt
1647

$ perl -F, -lane'push @a,$F[3];END{foreach(@a){ $sum +=$_ };print "$sum"}' file{1..3}.txt
1647
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -d, -f4 file{1..3}.txt | paste -sd+ - | bc
1647
```

Answer (score 0):

The paste method is only viable for smaller inputs. When row count gets somewhat larger, like the example below of `34,999,999`, compared to `awk`,

- `gnu-paste` is ~**2.83x** slower
- `bsd-paste` is ~***3.72x*** slower

---

** *adding `perl` for completeness* :::  `perl 5.36.0` is ~**1.54x** slower

```
perl -MList::Util=sum0 -F, -lane'push @a,$_;END{print sum0 @a}'
```

---

```
__='34999999'

( time ( jot "$__" | pvE0 | mawk2 'END { print +_ }{ _+=$__ }' ) )

sleep 1

( time ( jot "$__" | pvE0 | LC_ALL=C paste -sd+ - | bc ) )

sleep 1

( time ( jot "$__" | pvE0 | LC_ALL=C gpaste -sd+ - | bc ) )
```

|

```
      in0:  289MiB 0:00:06 [47.9MiB/s] [47.9MiB/s] [<=> ]
     1  612499982500000

( jot "$__" | pvE 0.1 in0 | mawk2 'END { print +_ }{ _+=$__ }'; )

  8.51s user 0.22s system 143% cpu 6.072 total

      in0:  289MiB 0:00:11 [25.5MiB/s] [25.5MiB/s] [ <=> ]
     1  612499982500000

( jot "$__" | pvE 0.1 in0 | LC_ALL=C paste -sd+ - | bc; ) 

27.87s user 1.15s system 128% cpu 22.594 total

      in0:  289MiB 0:00:06 [48.3MiB/s] [48.3MiB/s] [ <=> ]
     1  612499982500000

( jot "$__" | pvE 0.1 in0 | LC_ALL=C gpaste -sd+ - | bc; )

17.14s user 1.10s system 106% cpu 17.185 total
```